# Why has Google Docs' grammar check suddenly become so wonky?

Tags: google-docs

I've used Google Docs for journalling for the past year, and never really noticed issues. Recently however, I've noticed that it's been bringing up blue lines under the strangest things. Of course, I can mark the suggestion as "wrong" or "unclear", but it's unclear to me what has changed. Have Google employed a new grammaticality algorithm for their spell-checker?

To give an example, here's a sentence that was flagged:

> I had toast which I **didn’t** really like, but that’s okay.

The bolded word, "didn't", was flagged as ungrammatical. Here's all the variations I've tested - where there's no bold, that means nothing was flagged.

> I had toast which I **didn’t** really like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had toast, which I didn't really like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had corn which I **didn’t** really like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had a sandwich which I didn’t really like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had toast which I didn’t like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had a sandwich which I didn’t like, but that’s okay.
>
> I had toast which I didn’t really like.

So it only flags "didn't" in a really specific sentence context, in other words. I've seen plenty of other examples but this is the first one I've thought to document before correcting the flag. Because Docs doesn't provide grammaticality information like Word does, I can't tell where it's determining the error, either - is it because there's no comma before which? Removing the adverb "really" suddenly makes it acceptable, as does substituting toast for a sandwich - why?

Of course, this is not an EL&U question.

**My question is**: Is there a specific change that has suddenly (at least from my end) caused Google Docs' grammar suggestions to become so wonky? Has anyone else reported similar occurrences? And out of interest, do these grammar "errors" (as of yet I haven't flagged them,) get reproduced on your end?

Comment: It’s being flagged because it’s actually grammatically incorrect.

Comment: What's grammatically incorrect about it? Moreso, the selection seems completely arbitrary too: "didn't really like" is not okay in the first clause of a compound sentence, but it is okay as a simple sentence. "Didn't like" is okay though, and "didn't really like" also becomes okay if you change "toast" to "a sandwich". There must be something much weirder going on here if sandwiches or toast are the determinants of grammaticality.